# Javascript bind working with its instance

Tags: javascript, this

Lets take an object

```
var o = {a : 10 ,b:20,f:function(){ return this.a + this.b; }};
console.log(o.f())//30 works as expected
```

Now,

```
var o = {a:10,b:20,f:function(){ return this.a + this.b; }};
var p = o;
p.a = 1;
p.b = 4;
console.log(p.f()); // 5 works fine
console.log(o.f()); //5,it should 30 right but why it is showing 5
```

why is it working like this. If i do `o.f()` it should get the value from object `o`.

It looks like i have not understood the bind properly

```
console.log(o.f.bind(o)())//gives 5
console.log(o.f.bind(this)())//gives 30
```

please give the difference between these two lines codes.

Comment: values in `o` changed already .

Comment: `console.log(o.f.bind(this))`  , what is `this` ?

Comment: I get NaN on `o.f.bind(this)()`

Comment: it look like in console i had a window.a and window.b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning an `object` reference to another one variable, not a copy.

```
var o = {a:10,b:20,f:function(){ return this.a + this.b; }};
var p = o; //Assigning the reference of o to p.
```

Hence it is behaving like that and this is how the language works.

When comes to your second question,

```
console.log(o.f.bind(o)()); // 5
```

This doesn't have any effect at all. You are not at all changing the `this` value of that function.

But the second line of code,

```
console.log(o.f.bind(this)()); // NaN
```

Changes the `this` value of that function to the `this` value of the context where the `bind` is being executed. For example, If you are executing it from window's context, `this` would be `window`, `window.a` will be `undefined` and `window.b` will also be `undefined`. So `undefined + undefined` will return `NaN`. Not `30` as you are saying.

Comment: `console.log()` both the variables after `assignment`

Comment: OMG i forgot completely, what about the second question about bind

Answer (score 2):

In the second block of code, `o` and `p` are the *same object*.

That is, `p.a` and `o.a` refer to the same value:

```
var o = {x: 5, f: function() {return this.x;}};
var p = o;
o.x = 10;
console.log(p.x) // 10
```

The results of your second block of code aren't related to `this` or `bind`.

---

`.bind(newObject)` makes a new function with the value of `this` "changed" to the specified `newObject`. (Aside: It usually doesn't make sense to use `this` outside of a method, because it will be defined as `window` [which also holds all global variables].)

For example, consider these objects:

```
var u = {x: 5, f: function() {return this.x;}};
var v = {x: 20};
```

If you want to "copy" the method from `u` to `v`, you could do this:

```
v.f = u.f.bind(v);

console.log(u.f()) // 5 // .bind() doesn't change the old function
console.log(v.f()) // 20
```

Answer (score 1):

`p = o` copies a reference, not creates a new object. Using a constructor function (with `f()` in prototype) or closure could be what you are looking for.